# Why the classifying space $BG$ has a non-trivial cohomology $H^∗(BG;A)$ with coefficients in a group $A$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

The assertion that $BG$ has non-trivial cohomology $H^∗(BG;A)$ depends on the group $G$ and the choice of $A$. If $G$ is finite and $A=Q$ then $H^∗(BG;Q)=0$, and more generally if $A$ is an abelian group in which multiplication by $|G|$ is an isomorphism  $H^∗(BG;A)=0$.

I try to understand but I still don't understand well why any fiber bundle over $X$ is equivalent to a homotopy class of maps  $X\rightarrow(BG)$

Can you provide me some example?

What does it mean "*The universal bundle $EG$ over the classifying space BG, has the property that for $Y=BG$ and $E=EG$, if $f*[EG]$ and $g*[EG]$ are isomorphic over $X$, then $f$ and $g$ are homotopic*"?.

I need some examples to configure better this idea.

Comment: The question in the title and the question in your post seem unrelated. Also, for the question in the post, have you read a proof of this fact?